# how to send multiple check box item lists to class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to send all the selected checkbox items to the class how do i send it.if i use `check1.selectedvalue/item` it sends only one.so how do i do this

```
protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int z = 0; z < check1.Items.Count; z++)
   {
      if (check1.Items[z].Selected)
      {
         string checking = "\u2022" + check1.Items[z].Text ;
      }
   }

   Mail emailsystem = new Mail();
   emailsystem.GetEmail(comment.Text, StatusList.SelectedValue, check1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: What is `check1` a `CheckBoxList`? or something else?

Comment: Have a closer look at your code: You are walking through the list of selected items, assign them to a string and then forget that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to concatenate the text of checked checkboxes and pass it to you emailSystem

```
protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string checking = "";
   for (int z = 0; z < check1.Items.Count; z++)
   {
      if (check1.Items[z].Selected)
      {
         checking += "\u2022" + check1.Items[z].Text;
      }
   }

   Mail emailsystem = new Mail();
   emailsystem.GetEmail(comment.Text, StatusList.SelectedValue, checking );
}
```

Comment: This will not compile, `checking` should be defined outside the `for`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx), you can do the following:

```
protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    foreach (ListItem listitem in check1.Items)
    {
        if (listitem.Selected)
        {
           result += ("\u2022" + listitem.Text);
        }
    }
    Mail emailsystem = new Mail();
    emailsystem.GetEmail(comment.Text, StatusList.SelectedValue, result);
}
```